# Count each character and store as <K,V> pair

Tags: r

How can I count the unique characters from a given string and store it as a key - value pair in R programming using the base package? Here key will be the distinct character and value will be the occurrence of the character within the string.

Let's say I have the input string as `"hello"`. The expected output would be:

```
h -> 1
e -> 1
l -> 2
o -> 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `table` to count the frequencies after we split the string in letters. A simple `sapply` can convert it to a list if needed, i.e.

```
table(strsplit('hello', ''))
#e h l o 
#1 1 2 1 

#or

sapply(table(strsplit('hello', '')), list)
#$`e`
#[1] 1

#$h
#[1] 1

#$l
#[1] 2

#$o
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

R does not have any native hashmap support, although there is a `hashmap` package.  However, we can easily enough use a list here to simulate hashing functionality:

```
lst <- list()
for (i in strsplit('hello', '')[[1]]) {
    lst[[i]] <- ifelse(is.null(lst[[i]]), 1, lst[[i]] + 1)
}

lst
$h
[1] 1

$e
[1] 1

$l
[1] 2

$o
[1] 1
```

### Demo

Note that now accessing a key in the map just means accessing an entry in the list, e.g. `lst$l` returns 2, because `l` occurs twice in the string `hello`.